# How to move a constraint from one bone to another of the same rig type in Rigify

Tags: python, rigging, rigify

[image]
As you can see it states that Constraints are moved to another bone if I add CTRL- or DEF- to the constraint. But Unfortunately it does not work. The '@' works but It not moves the constraint to another bone, rather edits the sub target of the constraint.